# Android: "cannot resolve symbol" while importing a library

Tags: java, android

trying to import the files

```
import com.inducesmile.androidmapdrawroute.entityObjects.DirectionObject;
import com.inducesmile.androidmapdrawroute.entityObjects.LegsObject;
import com.inducesmile.androidmapdrawroute.entityObjects.PolylineObject;
```

a tag message reports

> Cannot resolve symbol 'inducesmile'.

like libraries are not available anymore.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I am using Android Studio 3.0.

Comment: Try cleaning / rebuilding your project.

Comment: After clean/rebuild, there is the Gradle error message: "package com.inducesmile.....  doesn't exist"